# How to call a macro from a sheet object

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I have a template file that connects to oracle and want to make a simple macro to refresh the oracle connection in every sheet, and I'll make a separate batch update file to open each of these files and call that macro. The `X = HypMenuVRefreshAll()` didn't work, so I tried `X = HypMenuVRefresh()`, and it only worked if I put it in the sheets themselves.

Can I have a module that loops through each of the sheets and calls that macro?
So I have something like this:
(The if statement is because the only sheets connected start with "CC ")

```
Sub Refresh_Workbook()

For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(ws.Name, 3) = "CC " Then
        Call EPBCS_Refresh_This_Sheet
    End If
Next Worksheet

End Sub
```

And the Refresh sheet code looks like this(This works fine if I run it on it's own):

```
Public Sub EPBCS_Refresh_This_Sheet()
    X = HypMenuVRefresh()
End Sub
```

But the module code is giving an error, because the sub i'm trying to call is undefined.
I think I could provide the sheet names specifically and call it that way, but the problem is that this is a template. So the sheet names need to be variable if that were the case so others can use this.

Any ideas?

I tried `X = HypMenuVRefreshAll()` and I got errors relating to other things in the file, so I tried `X = HypMenuVRefresh()` and that works only if I run it within the sheet object, not in the module object. I'm thinking when I try to run it in a module, it runs into other things, but in the sheet there's really no other code to interfere.

So I need to activate each sheet (variable name because this is a template), and run the code within that sheet's object.

Comment: *"so i'm stuck trying to slap together a solution "* ... And you're seeing this as an opportunity to get a skill that make you more valuable, right!? (It will!). Oracle has little to do with your problem. I'm add the vba and VB-script as a tags so the people that good at VB-script, vba and search here for questions to help with will find it. I don't have enough experience to help, so Good luck!

Comment: It's possible your question will be vote-closed because you're not follow all the rules for posting questions. As people write comments asking for more information be sure to reply in a timely manner. If you do get closed, repost and be sure to have responded to followup comments that ask for clarification or samples etc. Read [mcve] for starters. While MCVE is very generic, realize an ideal question would allow readers to cut/paste the smallest amount of code into their environment and see the same problems. Also, use the `{}` tool from Edit menu to get correct formatting for text/data/errMSG

Comment: It may be annoying to answer a bunch of comments, but people are only asking because they can't "see" your problem as if you were setting next to each other. Feel free to use my id `@shellter` to have me look in  explaining the StackOverflow eco-system and "manners'. Good luck.

Comment: Hang in there. Maybe tomorrrow!